# $X$th Permutations of $1,2,3,4,5$ is $25314$. Find X

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, factorial

The permutations of $1,2,3,4,5$ are lexicographically ordered.
$X$th permutation is $25314$. Find $X$.

I am getting $1*4! + 3*3! + 1*2! + 1=45$. Is it correct?

Reasoning:
There are $1*4!$ numbers of the form of $1X_1X_2X_3X_4$.
Similarly, there are $3*3!$ numbers of the form of $2YX_1X_2X_3$ where $Y \in \{1,3,4\}$. We continue the pattern this way to get the answer.

Comment: @PeterSmith Hello

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please explain your reasoning since that helps readers detect any mistakes you may have made.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Hello. I am done

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

There are $4!$ permutations which have a $1$ in the first position, all of which precede the first permutation which begins with a $2$.

Each permutation which begins with $21$, $23$, or $24$ precedes the first permutation which begins with $25$.  Since there are $3!$ permutations which begin with $21$, $3!$ permutations which begin with $23$, and $3!$ permutations which begin with $24$, there are $3 \cdot 3!$ permutations which begin with $2$ that precede the first permutation which begins with $25$.

Hence, there are $4! + 3 \cdot 3!$ permutations which precede the first permutation which begins with $25$.

Of the permutations which begin with $25$, those that begin with $251$ precede the first permutation which begins with $253$.  Since there are $2!$ permutations which begin with $251$, there are $4! + 3 \cdot 3! + 1 \cdot 2!$ permutations which precede the first permutation which begins with $253$.

Of the permutations that begin with $253$, $25314$ is the first.  Hence, the position of the permutation $25314$ if the permutations of $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ are listed in increasing order is indeed
$$4! + 3 \cdot 3! + 1 \cdot 2! + 1 = 45$$